# Fuzzing with a Quantum computer?

Tags: fuzzing, quantum-computing

Are there any projects, solutions, ideas where it is possible to fuzz a software:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzing

using quantum computers, quantum programming?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_computing

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_programming

or this combining is not yet possible?

Just thinking that in theory, with a quantum computer, you can check all possible states of a software (checking all possible inputs in a very short time).

Comment: I'm not sure that there would be projects yet when there aren't any quantum computers to develop the projects on.

Comment: Quantum computers are a marketing scam.

Answer (score 1):

> ...with a quantum computer, you can check all possible states of a software ...

While a quantum computer can hold multiple states at once these states do not magically get checked against some software written for a non-quantum environments. In order to fuzz such software it would be necessary to translate the software into some problem the quantum computer can actually work with first. Or one would need to translate the whole run time environment of the software (i.e. OS, libraries, CPU, ...) in order to analyze unmodified software within the quantum computer.

Given the current state of quantum computers and the problems they can solve and the efforts which would be needed to translate common software into some problem solvable through quantum computing, I don't think that there are any attempts of practical relevance to fuzz common software now and in the near future.